# Too Slow to Load the JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

im newbie in jsp jstl tag. i have a question, recently i build web application that can calculate outlet's total amount by revenue code. i make the query inside the jsp using jstl tag. the problem is my page take too long to load. i got about 60 outlet, 26 revenue code. 1 outlet can have at least 4 revenue code.

here is my code

in dashboard.jsp

```
 <sql:query var="outletView" dataSource="${datasource}">
                                    SELECT 
                                        outletid
                                    FROM 
                                        user_payment
                                   group by 
                                        outletid
                    </sql:query>
                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                                            <thead>
                                                <th> Outlet ID </th>
                                                <th> Revenue Code </th>
                                                <th> Total Transaction </th>
                                                <th> Total Amount </th>
                                            </thead>

                                        <c:forEach items="${outletView.rows}" var="rowOutlet">
                                            <sql:query var="outletView" dataSource="${datasource}">
                                                SELECT 
                                                    revcode,
                                                    count(receiptnumbe) as Transactions,
                                                    sum(amount) as total
                                                FROM 
                                                    user_payment
                                                Where 
                                                    outletid='${rowOutlet.outletid}'
                                                Group by 
                                                    revcode

                                            </sql:query>




                                                    <c:forEach items="${outletView.rows}" var="displayrevcode">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>${rowOutlet.outletid}</td>
                                                            <td>${displayrevcode.revcode}</td>
                                                            <td>${displayrevcode.Transactions}</td>
                                                            <td>${displayrevcode.total}</td>
                                                        </tr>

                                                    </c:forEach>


                                        </c:forEach>
```

can make it faster? i have to fetch and calculate each outlet's revenue code amount...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a single select statement instead of n+1 (where n is the number of distinct outletid):

```
SELECT 
    outletid, 
    revcode,
    count(receiptnumbe) as Transactions,
    sum(amount) as total
FROM 
    user_payment
GROUP BY 
    outletid, revcode
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: what do you mean by Order BY 1??

Comment: it's the same as `ORDER BY outletid` - if it's numeric it means the column order in the select statement

Comment: owh thank you for the explanation. its like array index start with 1.

Comment: hi orid.. i stumble new problem. i refactor the sql using your solution and it works. now im gonna stuck at how to display highest transaction.

 SELECT 
                outletid, 
                revcode,
                count(receiptnumbe) as Transactions,
                sum(amount) as total
            FROM 
                user_payment
            WHERE
                date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM user_payment GROUP BY date desc LIMIT 0, 1)
            GROUP BY 
                outletid, revcode
            ORDER BY 1

Comment: It's a different issue, and you should post it as a new question. Basically you can't have two group by clauses in query, but use a comma, same as in my example, and `desc` belongs to the order by clause. If for example you only need to change my query to sort first by outletid and then by highest transaction, change your order by clause to `ORDER BY 1, 3 desc`. Also you don't project (use in the select columns) the date column so no need to group by it. I suggest opening a new question tag it as `sql` give you table structure a explain what you try to acheive

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues:

1. Running query from JSP (directly/indirectly using a tag) is a bad practice. Query only from service layer.
2. Looping through one query result and running another query depending on the outer loop is a very bad practice. It typically leads to very slow running queries in production environment with large data sets. Use joins to avoid such queries.
3. This is a report functionality. Reports are rarely live. Usually a report is run on previous day's data. As far as possible pre-process the data for reports. In data warehouse terminology create the cubes for the data. These queries run offline and keep the report data ready for using when the user accesses the report.

Comment: so what i should do? move the queries to servlet>?

Comment: Separate view, controller and service layers. Run query from service layer. Try spring framework and spring MVC. Spring has beautiful features to separate the layers.